# How to install Oracle 11g?

Tags: 11.10, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Oracle 11g R2 in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168522/how-can-i-install-oracle-11g-r2-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts)

Question:

I'm trying to install oracle 11g on Ubuntu 11.10.

I got pretty far, using these 3 tutorials:

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9596361
http://blog.craigpoma.com/2010/07/installing-oracle-11gr2-on-fedora-13.html
http://lesscode.blogspot.com/2010/04/install-oracle-11g-r2-on-ubuntu-104.html

But now, I'm stuck with this one:

> INFO:
>   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/lib//libnlsnr11.a(nsglsn.o):
>   In function `nsglonsterm': nsglsn.c:(.text+0xc29): undefined reference
>   to`ons_subscriber_close' nsglsn.c:(.text+0xc3b): undefined reference
>   to `ons_shutdown_nowait'
>   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/lib//libnlsnr11.a(nsglsn.o):
>   In function`nsglma': nsglsn.c:(.text+0x1ffb): undefined reference to
>   `ons_subscriber_receive' nsglsn.c:(.text+0x251d): undefined reference
>   to`ons_notification_body' nsglsn.c:(.text+0x2a4b):  INFO: undefined
>   reference to `ons_subscriber_relinquish' nsglsn.c:(.text+0x2a62):
>   undefined reference to`ons_subscriber_receive'
>   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/lib//libnlsnr11.a(nsglsn.o):
>   In function `nsglonsinit': nsglsn.c:(.text+0x2d43c): undefined
>   reference to`ons_init' nsglsn.c:(.text+0x2d457): undefined reference
>   to `ons_subscriber_create_async' nsglsn.c:(.text+0x2d473): undefined
>   reference to`ons_subscriber_status' nsglsn.c:(.text+0x2dc94):
>   undefined reference to `ons_shutdown_nowait'

I think I see the problem
(the double slash in `/network/lib//libnlsnr11.a` )

But I don't know how to solve it...

The offending makefile seems to be this one:
(/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/lib/ins_net_server.mk )

```
# $Id: cus_net_server.mk 08-mar-2002.10:43:34 donlee Exp $
#
# cus_net_server.mk - "make" command file to reload tnslsnr, lsnrctl
#
# Used to reload tnslsnr, lsnrctl, after changing network protocol adapter.
#
# NOTE: ORACLE_HOME must be either:
#   . set in the user's environment
#   . passed in on the command line
#   . defined in a modified version of this makefile
#
# MODIFIED  (MM/DD/YY)
# donlee     03/08/02  - cannot use $<
# donlee     02/27/02  - define/use macro covers for INSTALL_TARGS
# donlee     02/26/02  - use relevant LINKLINE macros
# donlee     02/08/01 -  rm unneeded macro defs
# donlee     02/08/01  - rm unnecessary def of ECHO
# mkrohan    10/12/00  - Switch from LINKEXSYSLIBS to LINKLDLIBS
# mkrohan    05/20/00  - Bug #1304913
#

include $(ORACLE_HOME)/network/lib/env_network.mk

INSTALL_TARGS=clean $(INSTALL_NET_SERVER_TARGS)

tnslsnr: $(S0NSGL) $(SNSGLP) $(NSGLPNP)
    $(SILENT)$(ECHO) " - Linking $(TNSLSNR)"
    $(RMF) $@
    $(TNSLSNR_LINKLINE)

itnslsnr: tnslsnr
    -$(MV) -f $(BINHOME)tnslsnr $(BINHOME)tnslsnr0
    -$(MV) tnslsnr $(BINHOME)tnslsnr
    -$(CHMOD) 751 $(BINHOME)tnslsnr

lsnrctl: $(S0NSGLC)
    $(SILENT)$(ECHO) " - Linking $(LSNRCTL)"
    $(RMF) $@
    $(LSNRCTL_LINKLINE)

ilsnrctl: lsnrctl
    -$(MV) -f $(BINHOME)lsnrctl $(BINHOME)lsnrctl0
    -$(MV) lsnrctl $(BINHOME)lsnrctl
    -$(CHMOD) 751 $(BINHOME)lsnrctl

preinstall:
    -$(CHMOD) 755 $(BINHOME)

install: preinstall $(INSTALL_TARGS)

clean:
```

Which includes this one:

/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/lib/env_network.mk 
but this file is too large to post here...

See here for the download link:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html