# How do I install Oracle 11gR2 Enterprise in Ubuntu?

Tags: 11.10, installation, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Oracle 11g?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68331/how-to-install-oracle-11g)

I installed oracle 11gR2 *Enterprise Edition* in ubuntu 10.04 and 10.10 but I can't install it in ubuntu 11.10.
can anyone tell me how to install it in step by step?

Comment: you have installed in the previous versions right. Have you try to install oracle in the same way here in 11.10?

Comment: Yes.But in 11.04 and 11.10 while installing database showing lot of errors. I am using 32 bit os and 32 bit oracle enterprise edition software.