# Can I install Ubuntu 32-bit and Oracle 11g R2 on a 64-bit laptop?

Tags: oracle

I have x86-64 bit laptop.Can I install oracle 11g R2 on ubuntu 32bit on my laptop by installing ubuntu first,then 11g R2.Please help.

If anything more required,please tell me where can I find them?

Thanks & regards

Comment: Do you already know how to install Oracle 11g to Ubuntu?

Comment: Isn't the Oracle part off-topic?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can install Ubuntu 32-bit first on your 64-bit-capable laptop, and then install Oracle 11g R2 on Ubuntu.

Installing Ubuntu is the easy part; installing Oracle may be more difficult. For that, I recommend you refer to Flabricorn's [excellent answer just above or below this one...](https://askubuntu.com/a/168507/58612)

Answer (score 2):

Most 32-bit operating systems should work fine under a 64-bit computer, I'm currently running a 64-bit computer with Ubuntu in 32-bit. No problems should yet be encountered.

NOW, for Oracle 11g R2, there are some extras that should be installed because they aren't provided by default. But we'll get to those in a second, and a lot of them aren't fully necessary but they'll make it easier. NOTE: All terminal commands can be copied and pasted however pasting in terminal requires the keystroke *ctrl + shift + v*, anywhere else *ctrl + v* can be used instead.

Now [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-linuxsoft-085393.html) are the files, separating into two parts and in .zip format. You should be able to open them without issue and if you don't there is an unzip utility on the site. The unzip utility download wouldn't load on my end so an alternate would be to open terminal using *ctrl + alt + t*, and enter the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get install unzip
```

Then:

```
unzip {file}
```

Of course replacing {File} with the .zip archive.

NOW you can follow the install instructions by Oracle linked [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24323/toc.htm)

Comment: FYI, "how do I install Oracle 11g (/R2)" is a question that has been covered multiple times on AU: [1](http://askubuntu.com/questions/94215/how-do-i-install-oracle-11gr2-enterprise-in-ubuntu), [2](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68331/how-to-install-oracle-11g), etc. I note that all the existing answers are...unsatisfactory, IMO. I suggest you ask and answer your own question on how to install 11g R2.. :)

Comment: I was linking the instructions lest he/she not be able to install on their own. They're very... long and require a lot of formatting. I shall do my best... tomorrow, or this coming evening.

Comment: I understand, but my point is that your instructions are clearer than most of the "answers" that I've seen on here ;)

Comment: AH! Mis-Interpreted, I shall then!

Comment: Thanks, a decent answer and I pledge at least a +50 bounty award to your good self -- please be sure to point me to the QA when done.