# How to install Oracle 11g

Tags: dependencies, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Oracle 11g?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68331/how-to-install-oracle-11g)

How can I install oracle 11g in Ubuntu 11.10? 
I followed a link and it did not work. I migrated from Red Hat to Ubuntu and am more familiar with it, other wise I think Ubuntu is very good graphically.

Is Oracle 11g compatible with Ubuntu?

I thought I had all required dependencies for oracle 11g. Is there a requirement list somewhere?

Comment: Perhaps you could update you question with some details of what instructions you were following, how far you got through those instructions, and what errors you received.  Without that kind of information, it is unlikely that anyone can tell what went wrong for you.

Comment: Are you trying to install 11g r2?  Or the Express Edition?

Answer (score 0):

ORACLE_HOME/bin/oracle will access the /dev/shm ,but ubuntu has moved it as /run/shm,the link was not useful for oracle ,I modified the oracle file by okteta, replaced the /dev/shm to /run/shm, there are about 17+ been replaced,good luck to you!

Comment: Do u have .sh file for that ? or please explain me in detail.