# How to install Oracle 11g on Linux (non-VM)

Tags: installation, display, oracle

I'm totally new to Linux so please excuse my ignorance.

I've got Ubuntu Server installed on an HP Proliant DL server; no GUI available. I'm trying to install Oracle 11g on this server and I'm running into a lot of Xterm, xhost issues etc.

I've tried all the Googled solutions to no avail. Can anyone provide or link me to a step-by-step guide on how to install Oracle on Linux in a **non-VM** environment?

Comment: @SauravKumar that question talks about using the GUI, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer in [How can I install Oracle 11g R2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168522/how-can-i-install-oracle-11g-r2)

If you don't mind using 10g XE version (good enough for learning purpose), you can add the Oracle Open Source Software APT repository and use `apt-get` to install it.

Add `deb http://oss.oracle.com/debian unstable main non-free`

e.g.

`echo "deb http://oss.oracle.com/debian unstable main non-free" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list`

and then

add the key

```
wget http://oss.oracle.com/el4/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle  -O- | sudo apt-key add -
apt-get update && apt-get install oracle-xe
```

Start, stop and configure: `/etc/init.d/oracle-xe {start|stop|configure}`

See [Installing Oracle Database XE on Debian, Ubuntu, and Kubuntu](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linux/xe-on-kubuntu-087822.html)