# Cannot install Oracle 11R2 on Ubuntu 13.10 because package "gcc-c++-3.4.6" is missing during prerequisite checks

Tags: software-installation, 13.10, oracle

I am not able to install Oracle 11R2 on my Ubuntu 13.10 because package "gcc-c++-3.4.6" is missing.

I tried [How can I install Oracle 11g R2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168522/how-can-i-install-oracle-11g-r2) and [this](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2461988), but I still get this error:

> This is a prerequisite condition to test whether the package "gcc-c++-3.4.6" is available on the system. (more details)
> Expected Value :gcc-c++-3.4.6
> Actual Value :missing

[image]

I already used this command: `sudo apt-get install gcc make binutils gawk x11-utils rpm build-essential libaio1 libaio-dev libmotif4 libtool expat alien ksh pdksh unixODBC unixODBC-dev sysstat elfutils libelf-dev binutils lsb-cxx libstdc++5`

Answer (score 1):

On the top corner on left side check the box **ignore all**
Then click **next**

Note that this work only if you configure kernel parameters as below:

> **Edit */etc/sysctl.conf:***
>
> *nano /etc/sysctl.conf*
>
> **Add or amend the following lines:**
>
> ### Oracle 11g Kernel Parameters ####
>  fs.suid_dumpable = 1
>  fs.aio-max-nr = 1048576
>  fs.file-max = 6815744
>
> kernel.shmall = 2097152
>  kernel.shmmax = 536870912
>   kernel.shmmni = 4096
>
> ### semaphores: semmsl, semmns, semopm, semmni ####
>  kernel.sem = 250 32000 100 128
>  net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 9000
>
> 65500
>  net.core.rmem_default=4194304
>   net.core.rmem_max=4194304
>  net.core.wmem_default=262144
>   net.core.wmem_max=1048586

Hope that help

Comment: Your settings i already apply, the problem still come...

Comment: Did you tried the ignore all then next option ? If yes, may be you faced the same issue like me while linking libraries as described below

Comment: I have tried and then all processes crashed :|

Comment: I did the installation according to http://tutorialforlinux.com/2013/04/05/howto-install-oracle-11g-r2-database-linux-ubuntu-1204-precise-amd64/. May be this link can help you. Good luck