# oracle 11g enterprise edition installation: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: software-installation, oracle

I downloaded oracle Linux version from [oracle download link.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-linx8664soft-100572.html) I saw the documentation and followed every steps as said but now when I try to run:-

```
 . runInstaller
```

on my terminal it throws error given above and hence not being able to install oracle. 
I believe I have downloaded correct oracle as per my ubuntu.

`uname -a`:

```
Linux reddevil 4.8.0-22-generic #24-Ubuntu SMP Sat Oct 8 09:15:00 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`file runInstaller`:

```
runInstaller: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable, with very long lines
```

I have ubuntu 16.10

also most of the oracle installation guides on websites/YouTube are found to be on **rpm package**. but on oracle download website there is file packaged on zip format, why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Oracle 11g R2?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/168522/how-can-i-install-oracle-11g-r2)

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this guide](http://www2.hawaii.edu/~lipyeow/ics321/2014fall/installoracle11g.html) for installing Oracle 11g in Ubuntu. Works flawlessly.

1) Download Oracle Database Express Edition

Download [Oracle Database Express Edition 11g Release 2 for Linux x64](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html).

2). Follow pre-install instructions:

a) Open terminal in which you downloaded the file and unzip using the command:

```
unzip oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip
```

b) Install required packages using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install alien libaio1 unixodbc
```

c) Convert RPM package format to DEB package format (that is used by Ubuntu) using the command:

```
sudo alien --scripts -d oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
```

d) Create the required chkconfig script using the command:

```
sudo pico /sbin/chkconfig
```

The pico text editor is started and the commands are shown at the bottom of the screen. Now copy and paste the following into the file and save:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Oracle 11gR2 XE installer chkconfig hack for Ubuntu
file=/etc/init.d/oracle-xe
if [[ ! `tail -n1 $file | grep INIT` ]]; then
echo >> $file
echo '### BEGIN INIT INFO' >> $file
echo '# Provides: OracleXE' >> $file
echo '# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog' >> $file
echo '# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog' >> $file
echo '# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5' >> $file
echo '# Default-Stop: 0 1 6' >> $file
echo '# Short-Description: Oracle 11g Express Edition' >> $file
echo '### END INIT INFO' >> $file
fi
update-rc.d oracle-xe defaults 80 01
```

e) Change the permission of the chkconfig file using the command:

```
sudo mod 755 /sbin/chkconfig
```

f) Set kernel parameters. Oracle 11gR2 XE requires additional kernel parameters which you need to set using the command:

```
sudo pico /etc/sysctl.d/60-oracle.conf
```

Copy the following into the file and save:

```
# Oracle 11g XE kernel parameters  
fs.file-max=6815744  
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range=9000 65000  
kernel.sem=250 32000 100 128 
kernel.shmmax=536870912
```

g) Verify the change using the command:

```
sudo cat /etc/sysctl.d/60-oracle.conf
```

h) You should see what you entered earlier. Now load the kernel parameters:

```
sudo service procps start
```

i) Verify the new parameters are loaded using:

```
sudo sysctl -q fs.file-max
```

j) You should see the file-max value that you entered earlier.
Set up `/dev/shm` mount point for Oracle. Create the following file using the command:

```
sudo pico /etc/rc2.d/S01shm_load
```

k) Copy the following into the file and save.

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
start) mkdir /var/lock/subsys 2>/dev/null
       touch /var/lock/subsys/listener
       rm /dev/shm 2>/dev/null
       mkdir /dev/shm 2>/dev/null
       mount -t tmpfs shmfs -o size=2048m /dev/shm ;;
*) echo error
   exit 1 ;;
esac
```

l) Change the permissions of the file using the command:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/rc2.d/S01shm_load
```

m) Execute the following commands:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/awk /bin/awk 
sudo mkdir /var/lock/subsys 
sudo touch /var/lock/subsys/listener
```

n) Install the oracle DBMS using the command:

```
sudo dpkg --install oracle-xe_11.2.0-2_amd64.deb
```

o) Configure Oracle using the command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure
```

Enter the following information:
A valid HTTP port for the Oracle Application Express (the default is 8080)
A valid port for the Oracle database listener (the default is 1521)
A password for the SYS and SYSTEM administrative user accounts
Confirm password for SYS and SYSTEM administrative user accounts
Whether you want the database to start automatically when the computer starts (next reboot).

p) Setup environment variables by editing your .bashrc file:

```
pico ~/.bashrc
```

Add the following lines to the end of the file:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
export ORACLE_SID=XE
export NLS_LANG=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh`
export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

q) Load the changes by executing your profile:

```
. ~/.profile
```

r) Start the Oracle 11gR2 XE:

```
sudo service oracle-xe start
```

s) Add user YOURUSERNAME to group dba using the command

```
sudo usermod -a -G dba YOURUSERNAME
```

t) Start the Oracle XE 11gR2 server using the command:

```
sudo service oracle-xe start
```

u) Start command line shell as the system admin using the command:

```
sqlplus sys as sysdba
```

Enter the password that you gave while configuring Oracle earlier. You will now be placed in a SQL environment that only understands SQL commands.

Create a regular user account in Oracle using the SQL command:

```
create user USERNAME identified by PASSWORD;
```

Replace USERNAME and PASSWORD with the username and password of your choice. Please remember this username and password. If you had error executing the above with a message about resetlogs, then execute the following SQL command and try again:

```
alter database open resetlogs
```

Grant privileges to the user account using the SQL command:

```
grant connect, resource to USERNAME;
```

Replace USERNAME and PASSWORD with the username and password of your choice. Please remember this username and password.
Exit the sysadmin shell using the SQL command:
exit;
Start the command line shell as a regular user using the command:

```
sqlplus
```

You will be prompted for a username and password. Once authenticated, you will be able to type in the standard SQL commands